# How to evaluate BASH-Like commands (if/elif/else) statements within Python 2.7

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, argparse

I am creating a Hacking Sim game.

Within my game, I am trying to implement BASH scripts for players to use.

Do note:

- Players can share scripts with other players
- All "BASH" commands are custom, and handled by my game
- Commands are currently handled by argparse
- This game is for Windows, written in Python2.7

Here is an example of how i process commands:

```
class Console():
    def do_echo(self, args):
        cmd_echo = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Prints out whatever you pass it", prog='echo')
        cmd_echo.add_argument("text",  metavar=("<text>"), help="The text to echo (\"in quotes\")", default=None)

        # Processes the command - Capture '--help' or argument errors (e.g: Typos)
        try: arg = cmd_echo.parse_args(args)
        except SystemExit: return # Voids the SystemExit that argparse calls, while allowing other errors

        print arg.text

def run(command)
    sys_args = shlex.split(command)
    if 'do_'+sys_args[0].lower() in dir(Console):
        function = sys_args[0] ; sys_args.pop(0)
        fn = 'Console().do_%s(%s)' % (function,sys_args)
        eval(fn)
```

When processing scripts(.sh) I am just using `for line in f.readlines(): run(line)`. (Yes, I know "eval is badddd" but i actually TRIED to exploit the process and came up with nothing.) Commands sent from the In-Game Terminal are parsed the same way.

However, i need to know how to process`if/else/for/etc..`

How can i implement this in my current code?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139708/discussion-on-question-by-cyanite-how-to-evaluate-bash-like-commands-if-elif-el).

Comment: @Bhargav Some of the comments (spesifically the last few) were relevant to the post.

Comment: Yep, they are all archived here http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/139708

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately if you want user programmable scripts you'll need to do some sort of interpreting and execution. Also, depending on how important security is to you, you have to consider the context with which those scripts are executing, and what they can do.

I highly suggest you start with something like: http://norvig.com/lispy.html. This is a really simple example of implementing a interpreted language on top of python. Best of luck!

Comment: All of the existing commands are ones i spesifically created within my game. I just want to know how to execute if and for commands spesifically.

Comment: I understood that, that's exactly why you need to write an interpreter. If you read through the link, I am sure you will find it very useful.

Comment: I already skimmed over that this morning. I already have 90% of the code i need, i just need to know how to parse multiline commands. Spesifically `if [$var1 == $var2] then <run code> fi`